# How to use apt-get on Ubuntu Core ARM?

Tags: ubuntu-core

I have running Ubuntu Core on my PandaBoard following [this guide](http://www.omappedia.com/wiki/OMAP_Ubuntu_Core).
Ubuntu Core has apt-get so I can install new packages but everything I want to install fails. I have used:

- `apt-get update`
- `apt-get update --fix-missing`
- `apt-get install xxxx`
- `apt-get upgrade`

But always getting errors. If I disconnect internet I get exactly the same error so I think I am not getting internet from my Ethernet cable. I have installed Ubuntu Server and I can install everything correctly but Ubuntu server is 1.6Gb vs 20Mb of Ubuntu Core. 
Ubuntu Core is supposed to have internet access but I can't even test it because I don't have "ping".

For example, here is what I get when tried to install `apt-get install aptitude`:

```
root@localhost:/home/andres# apt-get install aptitude
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apt-xapian-index file iso-codes libapt-inst1.4 libboost-iostreams1.46.1
  libclass-accessor-perl libclass-isa-perl libcwidget3 libept1.4.12 libexpat1
  libgdbm3 libio-string-perl liblocale-gettext-perl libmagic1
  libparse-debianchangelog-perl libsigc++-2.0-0c2a libsqlite3-0
  libsub-name-perl libswitch-perl libtimedate-perl libxapian22 lsb-release
  mime-support netbase perl perl-modules python python-apt python-apt-common
  python-chardet python-debian python-xapian python2.7 xz-lzma
Suggested packages:
  app-install-data python-xdg aptitude-doc-en aptitude-doc tasksel debtags
  isoquery libcwidget-dev libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-template-perl
  libxml-simple-perl xapian-tools lsb perl-doc libterm-readline-gnu-perl
  libterm-readline-perl-perl make libpod-plainer-perl python-doc python-tk
  python-apt-dbg python-gtk2 python-vte python-apt-doc xapian-doc
  python2.7-doc binutils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-xapian-index aptitude file iso-codes libapt-inst1.4
  libboost-iostreams1.46.1 libclass-accessor-perl libclass-isa-perl
  libcwidget3 libept1.4.12 libexpat1 libgdbm3 libio-string-perl
  liblocale-gettext-perl libmagic1 libparse-debianchangelog-perl
  libsigc++-2.0-0c2a libsqlite3-0 libsub-name-perl libswitch-perl
  libtimedate-perl libxapian22 lsb-release mime-support netbase perl
  perl-modules python python-apt python-apt-common python-chardet
  python-debian python-xapian python2.7 xz-lzma
0 upgraded, 35 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 18.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 65.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main liblocale-gettext-perl armhf 1.05-7build1
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise-updates/main libsqlite3-0 armhf 3.7.9-2ubuntu1.1
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main libgdbm3 armhf 1.8.3-10
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main libsigc++-2.0-0c2a armhf 2.2.10-0ubuntu2
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main libmagic1 armhf 5.09-2
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main file armhf 5.09-2
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main mime-support all 3.51-1ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise-updates/main python2.7 armhf 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main python armhf 2.7.3-0ubuntu2
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main lsb-release all 4.0-0ubuntu20
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main netbase all 4.47ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main iso-codes all 3.31-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main python-apt-common all 0.8.3ubuntu7
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main python-apt armhf 0.8.3ubuntu7
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main xz-lzma all 5.1.1alpha+20110809-3
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main libxapian22 armhf 1.2.8-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main python-xapian armhf 1.2.8-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main python-chardet all 2.0.1-2build1
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main python-debian all 0.1.21ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main apt-xapian-index all 0.44ubuntu5
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main libboost-iostreams1.46.1 armhf 1.46.1-7ubuntu3
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main libcwidget3 armhf 0.5.16-3.1ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main libept1.4.12 armhf 1.0.6~exp1ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main aptitude armhf 0.6.6-1ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main libswitch-perl all 2.16-2
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main libclass-isa-perl all 0.36-3
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise-updates/main perl-modules all 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.1
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise-updates/main perl armhf 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.1
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main libsub-name-perl armhf 0.05-1build2
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main libclass-accessor-perl all 0.34-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main libio-string-perl all 1.08-2
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main libtimedate-perl all 1.2000-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise/main libparse-debianchangelog-perl all 1.2.0-1ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise-security/main libapt-inst1.4 armhf 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.2
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise-security/main libexpat1 armhf 2.0.1-7.2ubuntu1.1
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-inst1.4_0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.2_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/libl/liblocale-gettext-perl/liblocale-gettext-perl_1.05-7build1_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/s/sqlite3/libsqlite3-0_3.7.9-2ubuntu1.1_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/g/gdbm/libgdbm3_1.8.3-10_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/e/expat/libexpat1_2.0.1-7.2ubuntu1.1_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/libs/libsigc++-2.0/libsigc++-2.0-0c2a_2.2.10-0ubuntu2_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/f/file/libmagic1_5.09-2_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/f/file/file_5.09-2_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/m/mime-support/mime-support_3.51-1ubuntu1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/p/python-defaults/python_2.7.3-0ubuntu2_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/l/lsb/lsb-release_4.0-0ubuntu20_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/n/netbase/netbase_4.47ubuntu1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/i/iso-codes/iso-codes_3.31-1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/p/python-apt/python-apt-common_0.8.3ubuntu7_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/p/python-apt/python-apt_0.8.3ubuntu7_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/x/xz-utils/xz-lzma_5.1.1alpha+20110809-3_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/x/xapian-core/libxapian22_1.2.8-1_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/x/xapian-bindings/python-xapian_1.2.8-1_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/c/chardet/python-chardet_2.0.1-2build1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/p/python-debian/python-debian_0.1.21ubuntu1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/a/apt-xapian-index/apt-xapian-index_0.44ubuntu5_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/b/boost1.46/libboost-iostreams1.46.1_1.46.1-7ubuntu3_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/c/cwidget/libcwidget3_0.5.16-3.1ubuntu1_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/libe/libept/libept1.4.12_1.0.6~exp1ubuntu1_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/a/aptitude/aptitude_0.6.6-1ubuntu1_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/libs/libswitch-perl/libswitch-perl_2.16-2_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/libc/libclass-isa-perl/libclass-isa-perl_0.36-3_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/p/perl/perl-modules_5.14.2-6ubuntu2.1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/p/perl/perl_5.14.2-6ubuntu2.1_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/libs/libsub-name-perl/libsub-name-perl_0.05-1build2_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/libc/libclass-accessor-perl/libclass-accessor-perl_0.34-1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/libi/libio-string-perl/libio-string-perl_1.08-2_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/libt/libtimedate-perl/libtimedate-perl_1.2000-1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/libp/libparse-debianchangelog-perl/libparse-debianchangelog-perl_1.2.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
root@localhost:/home/andres#
```

And using "apt-get update":

```
root@localhost:/home/andres# apt-get update
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com precise InRelease

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease

Err http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease

Err http://ports.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/precise/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/precise-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/precise-security/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiomap-dev/release/ubuntu/dists/precise/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiomap-dev/release/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/precise-updates/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/precise-security/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@localhost:/home/andres#
```

Comment: And what is that mysterious error message then?

Comment: " Ubuntu Core is supposed to have internet access but I can't even test it because I don't have "ping"."  you do not need ping to test internet. wget works just as well as a test.

Comment: could you post what you can get from sudo apt-get update ?

Comment: I have edited my question with "apt-get update" and "apt-get install aptitude" output

Comment: @Rinzwind Ubuntu Core doesn't have wget :/

Answer (score 2):

This is probably happening because the image doesn't know any nameservers.

You can fix this by adding a nameserver e.g. [Google DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/)

> echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf

You may also need to get your kernel to handle DHCP autoconfiguration, if it's not doing that already.